# Is it possible to get a reference of the array of selected values on a Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 which is multiple select.

There are two ways to select an option:
Type and choose on the select box,
There is a menu on which you can click and it will add it to the select2 select box.

It's not properly working this time, but I can already select options using the menu.

What I want to know is, is it possible for me to have a reference of the array of selected values?

Because what I am doing right now is,
I have an array called, `selectedValuesArray`,
where when I select from the menu, it will push the id of the selection to the `selectedValuesArray` and

```
$('#selectbox').val(selectedValuesArray).trigger("change");
```

So can I just have a reference on the array of the selected value itself so I'll just push and splice items there?

EDIT:
Select2.val() is an array.
I want to have a reference to that array like,
    var selectionArray = Select2.val();
And I want to manipulate that array dynamically.
    // like adding a selection
    selectionArray.push("1");
    // or removing a selection
    selectionArray.splice(indexOf("1"), 1);

Is it possible?

Comment: You can get selected values of select2 like: $('#selectbox').val();  and this will give you an array of selected option's values.

Comment: To clarify what you are asking. You are currently making your own array of select values into an array called `selectedValuesArray`. And basically wondering if there is a way to get that array without having to make it yourself? Is that what you are asking? I'm just not certain what the question is here.

Comment: $('#selectbox').val() returns an array right? that is the array i want to have a reference to. I want to manipulate that array, so I don't have to create another array and set it to the $('#selectbox')'s array. So I can just push and splice on to that array, not push and splice to an array and set the selectbox array.

Comment: selectedValuesArray is a temporary array for getting the values and then adding it to the selectbox array

Comment: yes @Qsprec , can i have a reference to that array? as in, when I refer to it and manipulate the reference, it will also be manipulated.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to change that array and set this to the select2 element. You can change this array and set it to select2 like: $('#selectbox').select2('val',createdArray).trigger('change'); I don't know any solution to referance the created array to select2 without setting the value of select2. I think you have to set the value whenever you change the selected option values

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't delete selections like for example I've already added Blue, even if there's no 'Blue' in createdArray, it will not be deleted. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question properly, you're after something like this:

```js
$("#e1").select2();

$("#checkbox").click(function () {
    if ($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) {
       $("#e1 > option").prop("selected", "selected");
       $("#e1").trigger("change");
    } else {
       $("#e1 > option").removeAttr("selected");
       $("#e1").trigger("change");
    }
});

$("#button").click(function() {
   console.log($("#e1").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css">

<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Select All
<input type="button" id="button" value="Check Selected" />
```

Original fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeadr/62/).

Comment: i will try this :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I will certainly try this even if it's a different approach. Wait :)

Answer (score 2):

Alright I have managed to achive what you want. Here is the code;

```
var selectedArray = $('#selectbox').val();
var selectElem = $('#selectbox').select2();

//delete '42' from array
var index = selectedArray.indexOf('42');
data.splice(index,1);
selectElem.val(selectedArray);
selectElem.trigger('change');

//add '52' to array
selectElem.push('52');
selectElem.val(selectedArray);
selectElem.trigger('change');
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hey Qsprec, thanks for the input. But this was my first attempt, and it was working, but @gotnull provided a better way.

Comment: It's okay if you solved your problem but this works too. Using that code now at my project also.